# Подмодули в Android

Tags: android, архитектура

Всем привет, захотелось реализовать подмодули из VIPER(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZPQ_qotx4M) по Clean Architecture.
Т.е. у каждого подмодуля свои контейнер, презентер, интерактор и т.д.

Чтобы можно было биндить их сразу к активити или фрагменту, решил вначале их реализовать как *CusomView*. Это бы позволило легко переиспользовать эти подмодули в других местах приложения.

Должно было получиться нечто вроде(на примере экрана отправки письма):

```
<ViewGroup>
  <EmailHeaderView/>   //заголовок письма: поля от кого и кому
  <EmailBodyView/>     //поля ввода
  <EmailActionsView/>  //кнопки действий: оправить, прикрепить аттач, сохранить в корзину
</ViewGroup>
```

Вот тут возникает проблема: у *CustomView* нет каноничного способа получения родителя *Fragment* или *Activity*, и соответственно мы не можем заинжектиться к ним. Можно конечно, заинжектиться к *Application*, но это ломает иерархию дерева зависимостей.

Можно использовать вместо *CustomView* фрагменты.

```
<ViewGroup>
  <fragment name=EmailHeaderFragment/>
  <fragment name=EmailBodyFragment/>
  <fragment name=EmailActionsFragment/>
</ViewGroup>
```

Это решает проблему с иерархией дерева зависимостей. Но возникает другая проблема: мы не можем просто забиндить эти подмодули в экране используя *ButterKnife*, придется каждый подмодуль вытягивать из *fragmentManager* по *id* или тегу руками.
Может, у кого-нибудь есть мысли, как еще можно реализовать подбные подмодули?

Answer (score 0):

пока выбрал 2-й вариант: создал свою *@BindFragment* аннотацию для филда экрана. К ней биндится *FragmentFieldBinder*, который смотрит id фрагмента и вытягивает по ней нужный из *fragmentManager*-a